# When is a composition of homeomorphisms topologically transitive provided one of the two is?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, chaos, topological-dynamics, homeomorphism

Suppose that $S$ is a (connected) regular surface, possibly with boundary, for instance an annulus. Suppose that both $f$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms whose restriction to $\partial S$ is the identity. Assume that $f$ is topologically transitive: $$\exists x\in S: \overline{\mathcal{O}_f(x)}=S.$$ Are there some nice assumptions on $g$ ensuring that $g \circ f$ is topologically transitive too? What is known about the minimal assumptions?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ commute it's immediate, but maybe that's not the kind of condition you want

Comment: It's also false in general: if $g=f^{-1}$ then $f$ and $g$ commute but $f\circ g=\mathrm{Id}_S$ is not topologically transitive.

Comment: Probably assuming $S$ is connected would be useful. For otherwise one could take any TT $h:S \to S$ and define a new map $f: S\times\{0,1\}\to S\times \{0,1\}$ by $(x,0)\mapsto (h(x),1)$ and $(x,1)\mapsto (x,0)$. Then $f$ is TT but $f\circ f$ is not.

Comment: Also I should mention in the literature the property that all positive iterates of a map being topologically transitive goes by the name of "total topological transitivity".

Comment: @AlpUzman Right. Specified.

Comment: It seems to me there should not exist any "nice" condition: for every TT homeomorphism $h$ fixing pointwise the boundary, $g:=h\circ f^{-1}$ is an example, and all examples are of this sort. You thus have a natural identification between TT homeomorphisms and the homeomorphisms you seek, and any condition (for $g$) will rephrase into a characterization of TT (for $h$).